# Is there a way to get the .txt file I am creating and writing to with this code to be named after the text in the top left cell of the selected area?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and am trying to write a module that creates and writes a .txt file containing the information in the active cells as part of a bigger project to automate reports. The module will loop through, activating specific cells until its finished (but this will be part of a different module). I need the file to be named after the top left cell in the selected range but cannot figure out how to integrate this.

```
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j  As Integer
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\(Cells(B, 7).Value).txt"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
Print #1, cellValue
Else
    Print #1, cellValue,
End If

    Next j
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

I expected `Application.DefaultFilePath & "\(Cells(i, j).Value).txt"` to name the file after the first cell but instead it names my file (Cells(i, j).Value).txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in quotes will be treated literally so you need to remove that bit from inside, viz

```
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Cells(7,"B").Value & ".txt"
```

To base on the top left of selection

```
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Selection(1).Value & ".txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This returns a 1004 Application-defined or object defined error on this line.

Comment: `B` isn't defined - did you mean column B? Otherwise need to know what it represents.

Comment: I did mean Column B. I had put there as a test to see if it would work at all but the end goal is to have the file be named after the top left cell in whatever range is selected.

Comment: hi, just replace the B with the number 2 (second column)

Comment: Have added a second line.